# Relation (x > 1)-to-many

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

It's probably more a generic question about database, than a django one but let's go.

I have very often what could be considered as 2-to-many relations.
For example, I have a class Match in my project, which is an encounter between two teams.

At first, I was using many-to-many:

```
Match(Model):
  teams = ManyToManyField('Team', related_name='matches') #Always two teams
```

It ended up being very inefficient for match related pages. Especially in django 1.3, because there is no equivalent to select_related for many_to_many relation. And it's a bit painful having to iterate when you now there is exactly two elements.

Then I switched to this model :

```
Match(Model):
  teams = ManyToManyField('Team', related_name='matches') #Always two teams
  team1 = ForeignKey('Team')
  team2 = ForeignKey('Team')
```

When I want to display match related pages, I can use select_related and display very efficiently the two teams.
And when I'm on the team page, I can follow the "matches" relation to get all the matches as before.
But I find that 3 fields to deal with one relation is totally horrible.

Am I doing it right ? What would you recommend ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your caching organisation ?

Comment: Two tags in titles, both with different delimiters... ARGH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few solutions there.

**1.**

If you're not anticipating that in future a match will be played between other number of teams than two it may be best for you to just remove a ManyToMany field from your second design:

```
Match(Model):
  team1 = ForeignKey('Team')
  team2 = ForeignKey('Team')
```

It'll remove a redundation in a database and makes `Match` modifications easier (you don't have to worry about cohesion between `team` field and corresponding `team1`, `team2` fields). It also makes impossible to create a Match with other number of corresponding teams than two, which leads to database consistency.

On the other hand you're losing a flexiblity and it's harder to write queries, because of two fields to check instead of one.

**2.**

You may want to use a cache. In fact - those two fields you have are nothing other than that, but moving it to a dedicated cache database can make it more efficient and separates your main database from cached values, which leads to a clearer database design.

**3.**

Write your own ManyToMany fetcher. It's not very hard to do, but rather ugly. You have to select teams you're interested in and then somehow attach them to Match objects, e.g.:

```
matches # Match QuerySet
related_teams = Team.objects.filter(match__in=matches)
matches_map = {}
for t in related_teams:
    matches_map[t.match_id]= matches_map.get(t.match_id, []).append(t)

for m in matches:
    m.fetched_teams = matches_map[m.pk]
```

**3.5.**

New version of Django will have a `prefetch_related()` method which is meant to work with ManyToMany queries, but I suppose you don't have so much time.

Comment: 1. We deal two vs two matches (which are pretty rare in our situation) with temporary teams of two teams, so there is always two teams in a match. The "redundation" isn't an issue at all, the value never changes so it's not hard to ensure teams, team1 and team2 are correct during the creation.

Comment: 2. I don't understand, you are handling all your many to many relations in the cache ? like redis ? It sounds like a lot of consistency issues. I'd love to see a tutorial about that.

Comment: 3. I do that already for a lot of relations, I recommend using though which permits to select the intermediate relation (even if it's not explicitly determined) + select_related. But I find very ugly to iterate when there is always 2 relations.

Comment: 3.5 Yeah, I'm following the dev blog and I make dream of prefect_related at night ^^. I'm just afraid to push a beta on prod, but I can't wait to use that functionality.

Comment: Ad 2. I was thinking about that for a while and it seems that I was wrong here.The idea was to store whole related objects in some kind of very low access cost cache like memcache or so. When you need related objects - you just fetch them from cache. It's easy to deal with consistency problems just by clearing object cache during any modifications on it's ManyToMany field - it will be rebuilded on the next call. But I'm not really sure how much boost you'll have from that and if it's worth trying.